# camel restlet Json integration issue

Tags: java, json, restlet

I try to use the restlet in camel.  the request should be a JSON. but do not how to convert the JSON to java object.  here are code samples:

the client request:

```
$.ajax({
     url: '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/rs/search?restletMethod=POST',
type: "POST",
data: $('#searchRequest').serializeArray(),
contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
dataType: "html",
success: function (result) 
{
 $("#result #queryId").text(result);
},
error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
 alert(xhr.status);
 alert(thrownError.Message);
 }
});
```

RouterBuilder:

```
from("restlet:/search?restletMethod=POST").unmarshal("gson")
     .to("bean:restletHandler");
```

camelcontext.xml

```
<bean id="gson" class="org.apache.camel.component.gson.GsonDataFormat">    
    <property name="unmarshalType" value="domain.SearchRequest"/>
</bean>
```

I kept get the following exceptions:

com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1

the Body in Exchange is type of org.restlet.engine.io.UnclosableInputStream
looks like:

> sex=female&_sex=on&sex=male&_sex=on&_sex=on&_race=on&race=black&_race=on&race=indian&_race=on&_race=on&_race=on&gender=&medication=2345&_medication=on&_medication=on&_medication=on&_medication=on&_medication=on&_diagnosis=on&diagnosis=410.90&_diagnosis=on&_diagnosis=on&_diagnosis=on&_diagnosis=on&description=sdfdsfQuery RequestcloseID description request create date owner status complete date count

the stream in body do not look like Json,  so gson do not know how to convert it to object.
any help will be really appreciate!

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Use JSON.parse() and content-type must be set to application/json

Comment: Thanks for your reply!  when I pass the data as:{"demographics.sex":["female","male","unknown"],"demographics.race":"indian","medications.includeCodes":["2345","4567"],"medications.excludeCodes":"4567","diagnosis.includeCodes":["250.00","410.90","401.9"],"description":"cxzcxzc","gender":""} 
the object created after "gson" missing the string array: